# Set/remove onClick event of separate points in jQuery Plot

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I'm plotting a graph with jQuery Plot. The graph contents 2 lines with points. I set the the option `'clickable'` in grid on true. It makes all points clickable.

The question is how can I set only separate points clickable?

Here is my code:

```
d1 = [[889.0, y_max], [905.0, y_max], [915.0, y_max], [935, y_max]];
d2 = [[885.0, 0.4], [905.0, 0.6], [915.0, 0.34], [935, 0.39]];
options = {
    yaxis: { min: y_min, max: y_max },
    grid: { hoverable: true,
            clickable: true,
            borderWidth: 0 },
    legend: {
        show: true,
        noColumns: 4,
        container: $("#labeler"),
        labelFormatter: function (label, series) {
            var cb = label;
            return cb;
        }
    }
};

ed_data = [
    { data: d1,
      points: { show: true, symbol: "diamond" },
      lines: { show: false },
      color: "#FF0000"
    },
    { label: "Serie 1",
      data: d2,
      points: { show: true,
                symbol: "triangle" },
      lines: { show: true, 
               lineWidth: 1 }
     }];

 pl = $.plot($("#placeholder_top"), ed_data, options);
```

Comment: I've not really used flot, but I've had a look and can't see a way. Can you not make the click event call a function and distinguish between the points you need there though?

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is a bit of a hack, but it works. The idea is to expand the array that defines a data point from two elements (`x` and `y`) to three (`x`, `y`, and `clickable`). So you'd define your data something like this:

```
d2 = [[885.0, 0.4], [905.0, 0.6, true], [915.0, 0.34, false], [935, 0.39, true]];
```

The first point won't be clickable (its third element is `undefined`), the second and fourth will be (the third element for both is set to `true`), the third point won't be clickable (its third element is `false`).

Now, when you bind a `plotclick` event, you can easily filter out the items you won't respond to:

```
$("#chart").bind("plotclick", function (event, pos, item) {
    if (item) {
        var dataPoint = item.series.data[item.dataIndex];
        if (dataPoint[2]) {
            // respond to the click 
        }
    }
});
```